# How to get month of a date in a django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to include a month number in a queryset where the date is in a related model.  This is what I tried:

```
 OrderItem.objects.all().annotate(order_month=Sum('order__payment_date__month'))[0].__dict__

 Join on field 'payment_date' not permitted. Did you misspell 'month' for the lookup type?
```

and then I tried

```
 OrderItem.objects.all().extra(select={'order_month': "order__payment_date__month"})

 (1054, "Unknown column 'order__payment_date__month' in 'field list'")

 OrderItem.objects.all().extra(select={'order_month': "order.payment_date"}).select_related('Order')

 (1054, "Unknown column 'order.payment_date' in 'field list'")
```

But this works so no problem with order.payment_date

```
 OrderItem.objects.all().values('id','order__payment_date').select_related('Order')
```

I need it in the querset result as I'm using the queryset in Geraldo.  Anyone know how I can get this?

THE ANSWER was that in the extra section you need to specify what you want so the MySQL understands it.  In my case adding the app in front of the model name. In this case web_order.payment_date. This worked:

```
OrderItem.objects.all().extra(select={'order_month': "MONTH(web_order.payment_date)"}).select_related('order')[0].__dict__

{'product_id': None, 'order_id': 1L, 'price': Decimal("1.00"),  'order_month': 7L, 'id': 1L}
```

Comment: Why did you do a Sum here?

OrderItem.objects.all().annotate(order_month=Sum('order__payment_date__month'))[0].__dict__

Comment: What is a "sum of payment months" even supposed to mean?

Comment: As month is an integer I thought I could be clever and use annotate to add this field.  Sadly not!

Comment: Why do you need the month (rather than full date) in the first place?

Comment: I want to group and sum for each month in geraldo and can't find a way of extracting the month within geraldo so want to pass it as part of the queryset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to drop down into SQL to get this done, which sadly means the solution won't be database agnostic.

This works in Postgres:

```
# Grab the base queryset
items = Item.objects.all()

# Annotate
extra_query = "EXTRACT(MONTH FROM relatedtable.mydatefield)"
items = items.extra(select={'mydatefield_month': extra_query}

# We have to use a select_related so that 'relatedtable' is 
# available in the SQL statement.
items = items.select_related('relatedmodel')

print items[0].mydatefield_month
```

For MySQL you might try:

```
extra_query = "MONTH(relatedtable.mydatefield)"
```

Comment: Hmm - not getting it working.  See edit to original question.

Comment: Try changing select_related('Order') to select_related('order')

Comment: That didn't fix it but you put me on the right road!  Have put the working query in the question and I'm giving you the credit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

In Django 1.10+, you can use the `ExtractMonth` function.

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractMonth
OrderItem.objects.all().annotate(order_month=ExtractMonth('order__payment_date'))
```